# I'm trying to position google maps with a table row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my webpage when the page loads it loads a table generated by content from my database, and all markers are instantly loaded on the map, but I'd like to be able to click on the table row to center and zoom on the marker that it represents, I'm trying to figure it out but I'm new to JQuery/Javascript just kind of learning as I go.

Here is my JQuery function I'm working on..

```
$("table#listOfStops").find('tr').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {

      alert(arrMarkers.length);
      var num = $(this).data("num");
      for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {
        if ( arrMarkers.id == 'marker'+num) {
          map.setCenter(arrMarkers[i].position);
          map
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Here is my table:

```
  <table id="listOfStops" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Stop #</th>
    <th>Street Name</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  while($stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo '<tr  id="' . $i . '">';
    echo '<td>' . $gStopNumber . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $gStreetName . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  $i++;} $stmt -> close(); $mysqli -> close(); ?>  
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

On page load it loads this initialize function:

```
function initialize() {
  geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.7626362, -111.379652),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
  }
};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'),
  mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    deleteOverlays();
    addMarker(event.latLng);
    updateTextFields(latitude, longitude);
  });
  <?php while($stmt -> fetch()) { ?>
  var long = "<?php echo $gLongitude ?>";
  var lati = "<?php echo $gLatitude; ?>";
  var title = "<?php echo $gTitle; ?>"
  setMarker(lati, long, title);
  <?php } $stmt -> close(); $mysqli -> close();?>



}
```

and then sets each marker to the map and pushes them to an array using the setMarker function:

```
function setMarker(lat,lon, markerTitle) {
  var latLonMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLonMarker,
    map: map,
    icon: 'icon.png',
    title: markerTitle
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    $('#inputLatitude').val(this.getPosition().lat());
    $('#inputLongitude').val(this.getPosition().lng());
  });
  arrMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

I'm just having an impossibly hard time matching the table row to the proper marker spot in the marker array to set the position something like `map.setPosition(arrMarkers[i]);`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where should `$(this).data("num")` come from? There is nothing set for the tr-elements.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I was reading something on Stack Overflow, I don't even know what Data does it just seemed to fix his issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery.each function supplies the index of the each result.
If you modify the query to .find('tbody tr') the index should match the position in the array
So something like:

```
$("table#listOfStops").find('tbody tr').each(function(idx) {
  var rowNumber=idx;
  $(this).on('click', function() {  
        map.setCenter(arrMarkers[rowNumber].getPosition());
  });
});
```

Comment: I realised that I was still trying to use your marker id (which hasn't been set anywhere) - re editted

Comment: Hm, it's still not working, the array is filled with this `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` What does the idx do in the function?

Comment: Awesome that works perfect I'm so happy right now been on this for over 24 hours gave up yesterday and went to bed, could you explain to me what value that idx gets? Like what does function(idx) do?

Comment: The jquery object contains an array of html elements that match your selectors (in this case the <tr>s inside the tbody) $.each(func(idx){}) then iterates through the array and calls the function func on each of the <tr>s in turn, the idx value is the position in the array, in your case this maps directly to the position of the relevent marker in the markers array :)